# Reading & writing dates from Google Spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am importing almost 30,000 dates from one Google Spreadsheet to another with a Google Apps Script. My import from a sheet of 10,000 works fine, but the larger one doesn't. For the larger import, all dates are being imported 1 date in the past, so 1/1/2018 becomes 12/31/2017, etc.

I know Javascript handles dates a bit unusually, so I'm not sure why it's failing on one and working on the other. But mostly, I'm not sure how to increment the entire array (actually array of arrays) at once).

When I checked the date values in the GAS debugger, I noticed that the January 1, 2018 date was being returned as Sun Dec 31 17:00:00 GMT-07:00 2017. The working sheet is returning Mon Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT-06:00 2018. I checked the properties on both script files and the underlying spreadsheets, and both are set to GMT-7.

**EDIT**

First 12 rows of dates:
January 1, 2018
January 1, 2018
January 1, 2018
January 1, 2018
January 1, 2018
January 1, 2018
January 1, 2018
N/A
N/A
January 1, 2018
January 2, 2018

Output:
12/31/2017
12/31/2017
12/31/2017
12/31/2017
12/31/2017
12/31/2017
12/31/2017
N/A
N/A
12/31/2017
1/1/2018

The code I'm using is `destination.getRange(1,7,lastRow+1).setValues(source.getRange(2,columns[0],lastRow+1).getValues());`
I understand is is probably a timezone issue, but especially across an entire array, I don't know what to do about it.

Desired behavior: The output to be an exact copy from the first rows of the source data.

I hope that is clear/good enough. If there's anything else I need to do to get this out of on-hold, please let me know.

Comment: Can you show us a snippet of what the dates look like? There may be an offset or something. Beyond that you could just .map the array and return the item with an updated date.

Comment: @Marie I added the input and output for the first 11 source rows.

Comment: This type of problem is almost always due to time zone issues.

Comment: @Barmar that's what I've seen from my other searching, but I don't know how to resolve it since my other sheet imports just fine

Comment: I've checked the timezone settings on both source sheets and the destination sheet. All of them are set to USD-7. That's true of both the sheets themselves and the script files attached to them.

Comment: If you inspect the array contents in the debugger, you can see each time zone that the `Date`s are using. Please include that in your question. (Set a breakpoint after you read from the sheet by clicking the relevant line number.)

Comment: @tehhowch I've added that to the OP. It's confusing to me, though, since both the spreadsheet settings and script properties are GMT-7, but the array in the working sheet is being pulled to GMT-6.

Comment: Please share the result of executing [`Session.getScriptTimeZone()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getScriptTimeZone()) and  [`Spreadsheet#getSpreadsheetTimeZone()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSpreadsheetTimeZone())

Comment: @tehhowch That fixed it! It was showing no timezone for the spreadsheet through the script. I had checked it in the Spreadsheet Settings itself, so I didn't realize something wasn't saved or transmitted.

Comment: @tehhowch Please update this Question with your Answer once this is off hold so other's can find it and benefit from it.

Comment: @Spencer Please make sure to stick with this Question until the Answer is moved from the Comments into a Proper Answer so other's can benefit from it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The answer came through trying things from the comments, so I'm answering this to actually give what happened.

I had checked in *File > Spreadsheet Settings* in the Google Sheets UI, and *File > Project Properties* from the Script Editor, to verify that the time zone settings were the same - and they were.

However, when I ran [`getSpreadsheetTimeZone()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSpreadsheetTimeZone()) from the Script Editor, its output was blank. I manually changed the timezone to something else and then changed it back, and finally the script recognized the timezone and the issue was resolved.

I can't say what caused the Google Sheet's timezone setting to be wrong, only that getting it right made it all work.